# STM32f091rc UART Receive function returning only the last byte of the packet instead of the full data packet

Tags: arm, stm32, uart, cmsis, stm32f0

I have been working on STM32f091rc board, trying to get UART1 and UART2 work. I tried sending 8 bytes of packet from a controller to the STM board. Due to some reasons, my function is just displaying the last byte of the packet. My Receiving function is given below:-

```
uint8_t rxd[10];
void getChar (void) {

while(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_FLAG_RXNE) == SET) { // Check RXNE to 
//see if there is data
    for(j=0; j<8; j++) { 
        rxd[i] = (0xFF & (USART1->RDR));
    }
```

What am i doing wrong? Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UART->RDR` register has no buffers, it holds only the last fully received byte. If another byte is received, it will be overwritten.

You should ensure that the value in `RDR` is read out every time after a byte arrives, and before the next one is received. There are 3 basic ways to do it.

- **Polling**

Check the `RXNE` flag regularly, and read `RDR` *exactly once* when it's set. Repeat until you have the whole data packet. Reading a byte from `RDR` clears the `RXNE` flag, wait until it's set again before you read the next byte.

- **Interrupt**

Set the `RXNEIE` bit in `CR1` and enable the interrupt corresponding to the UART in `NVIC`. The interrupt handler will be called every time a byte is received. The handler can be very simple at first, just reading `RDR` and storing it in a buffer. Later you can add error checking and recovery. Don't forget to declare every variable the interrupt handler touches as `volatile`.

- **DMA**

Set up the DMA channel first (`USART1` is mapped to `DMA1_Channel3` by default, can be remapped, check the reference manual for others):

```
DMA1_Channel3->CPAR = (uint32_t)&USART1->RDR;
DMA1_Channel3->CMAR = (uint32_t)rxd;            // start of receive array
DMA1_Channel3->CNDTR = 8;                       // 8 bytes to receive
DMA1_Channel3->CCR = DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_EN; // Memory increment, enable
```

then set up the serial port, and enable DMA receive in `USART1->CR3`. The end of transfer is signaled in the `DMA1->ISR` register, you can check it regularly in the main program, or enable an interrupt in `DMA1_Channel3->CCR` (and in `NVIC`). You should clear the interrupt flag through `DMA1->IFCR`, otherwise you'll get endless interrupts when enabled. To start another transfer, set the `CNDTR` register again. Declare all variables touched by DMA or the interrupt handler as `volatile`.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable information. So now i conclude that the RXNE flag is set only when a byte is received and reading the RDR register clears the flag. Now i have changed the logic to this :-   uint8_t getChar (void) {
    
    if(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_FLAG_RXNE) == SET) { // Check RXNE to see if there is data
 return ((USART1->RDR) & (0xFF));
}         
       
     else {
        return 0xFF;
    }

}    -- This is my function getchar() and if i run this continuously in while(1), on returning the value, it should clear the flag RXNE right?

Comment: Then i think i have to store the byte before returning the value?

Comment: Either store the value in the function and return an error/success code,  or use an integer return type in the function, and return a negative value when nothing is received. The latter would be analogous to the `getchar()` library function.

Comment: According to what you had explained, i intend to use polling method in order to receive 8 bytes, this is my logic which does not seem to work:-    
char rxdata[2];

for (k=0; k<8; k++){   //checking the flag regularly till 8 bytes of data is obtained
 if(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_FLAG_RXNE) == SET) { // Check RXNE to see if there is data
 rxdata[0]=((USART1->RDR)&(0x00FF));  // putting the RDR value in the rxdata[0], reading exactly once  
}
else{     //if the flag is not set
UartTransmitPacket("flag reset", sizeof("flag reset")); //printing that the flag is reset
}
}

Comment: I have tried printing the the value of rxdata[0] after every iteration. still not getting it.

Comment: Your code checks the flag only 8 times. It should check the flag continuously until it is set.

Comment: for (k=0; k<8; k++){
data = getChar();
        if (data!=0xFF) {
            //putChar(data);
//if (data == 0x04){
//GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_5);
if (data == 0x01){
GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_5);
}

if (data == 0x08){
GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_5);
}
rxdata[k]=data;
        }
}
I am getting a blink so i know now that i am getting the whole packet. But now i see that the delay that i am applying in the while condition is affecting this getchar function.

Comment: I will try to strengthen the integrity of the packet by checking if the first byte is 0x01 or not. In Polling i will have to take care of the delays i guess. i will also try the interrupt method which can help me in improving the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for(j=0; j<8; j++) { 
  rxd[i] = (0xFF & (USART1->RDR));
}
```

you use `j` as a loop counter but you write to `rxd` under index `i`, not `j`. You overwrite the same byte 8 times.

Another thing is that you wait for the `USART_FLAG_RXNE` flag to be set, then you read from the `RDR` register 8 times. This flag is set when the first byte is received, then you read it 8 times - you very likely read much faster than the speed at which you send the data. If you want to do it by polling - which seems to be your intention - you should wait for the `USART_FLAG_RXNE` flag being set after reading each byte separately, as USART peripheral in this MCU has no FIFO and can only hold a single received byte for you to read (mentioned `RDR` register).

Comment: Yeah by mistake I wrote 'i' instead of 'j'. Thanks. I will try to get the logic correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is completely wrong.

```
for(j=0; j<8; j++) 
{
    while(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_FLAG_RXNE) != SET); // wait for the data
    rxd[i] = (0xFF & (USART1->RDR));
}
```